# Zip file structure in Linux

Tags: linux, zip

I have a file in `folder/football.jpg` that I want to zip. So I zip with the command

```
zip folder/football_zip folder/football.jpg
```

It works, except that the Zip file contains the folder `folder`, which contains `football.jpg`. How can I make the Zip file contain only `football.jpg`?

Comment: Your question is off topic for Stack Overflow.  Let's migrate it to superuser instead.

Comment: Why is it off topic for Stack Overflow, and what is superuser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask -- skip down to "if your question would be of interest to..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `zip` command has a `-j` switch that will do this:

```
zip -j folder/football_zip folder/football.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
cd folder
zip ../football.zip ./football.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
cd folder
zip football_zip football.jpg
```